# How to get notification of DLL loads happening in my software (inside my own process only)

Tags: visual-c++, exception, dll, floating-point, hook

First of all, some background:

My software which is written in VC++ relies on some large third party DLL's that get loaded along with my app. These libs often raise Floating point exceptions during their normal course of operation, but they are not signaled as hardware exceptions because of the default configuration of Floating point Control word to mask these exceptions and hence the program does not crash because of these.

Now the issue is that when some third party programs like **Zeallsoft Super Screen Capture** inject their own DLLs which are written in Borland C++, they set the FP Control Word to enable the Floating point exceptions and my app crashes because of that.

While the main issue might be with the third party lib and the third party software that is injecting its own Dll's, I still want to protect my software from crashing because of such an issue.

The solution that I can think of is to some how get notification of Dll loads happening inside my process and ensure that the FP control word is reset to default value after the dll load happens.

So I am looking for simple and effective ways to achieve that. Is there some way to get notified of Dll loads happening in my process? Are there any other way of achieving what I want to do? The only thing that I want to be wary of is that the method should work on Win 2k and WinXP and higher and secondly the method used should not be of a nature that can potentially trigger the malware heuristics of Anti-virus/spyware scanners.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the windows [Debugger API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically you want to monitor the [`LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) debug event. it should be noted that debugging yourself is dangerous as it can lead to app locking, it also means you can't debug it normally.

the alternative is do a process-wide [Hot Patch](http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=17) ([a better paper on it](http://www.phreedom.org/presentations/hotpatching-and-third-party-patches/hotpatching-and-third-party-patches.pdf)) hook on `LoadLibraryEx`, `LoadLibraryA` and `LoadLibraryW` and check the dll's passing through there.

the main problem with this is you need to make sure you install the hooks/monitors *before* anything else (that you care about) in the process loads, which may require more 'black magic'....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did manage to hook LoadLibrary calls through IAT patching and fix the issue, but the thing I am concerned about is whether this kind of patching triggers the heuristics of malware/virus scanners.

Answer (score -1):

[It is the responsibility of the DLL to restore the FPU state.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326219)

You can detect the FPU state problem [at the time of unhanded exceptio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)n and [reset the FPU state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx), but the dll may not behave correctly after that ([some people do rely on FPU exceptions](http://origin-software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=51174), and there is a reason why they enable it). You can notify the user that an incompatible dll is injected to your process which will cause unpredictable behavior.

You can also scan the program files folder ([or the Windows Installer database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and warn the user a known compatibility problem exists.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the DLL should restore the state of FP flags. But the thing is that Borland C++ is know to enable these FP flags by default and people do not often bother to disable them when the don't need them.

Comment: [Borland compilers and floating-point exceptions](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=53). It becomes especially problematic when such DLL's are injected into processes that have them disabled. While we do have an Exception Handler installed, handling this situation after an exception occurs would be doing it too late. One thing I tried is hooking LoadLibraryEx and resetting FP flags from there and it works